# Windows 10 Playback Sound Settings Interfering with Audio Playback

Tags: windows, audio, speakers

I have an extremely weird problem that I've never encountered before. I'm currently using a Dell Latitude hooked up to a Dell dock at work. Sometimes I use headphones that are plugged into the dock.

Whenever I plug or unplug headphones, Windows automatically changes the default playback device (expected behavior). Windows also changes the playback device when I undock the laptop because the monitors (which are plugged into the dock) also have speakers. So my current setup can output sound to three different devices: the laptop speakers, monitor speakers, or my headphones.

The problem I'm having is every once in a while (and every time the computer goes to sleep), I can't do anything that requires audio unless I unplug and plug my headphones back in. A typical scenario would be: I have my headphones plugged in and listening to Spotify. If I lock my computer and step away long enough for the laptop to go to sleep/turn off monitors and I come back, Spotify won't work and any thing else that requires audio also doesn't work (like Youtube). I couldn't figure out what the problem was for the longest time, but if I unplug/plug the headphones, those applications work again. If I disable/enable the playback device, same thing. It's really strange that a desktop application's (Spotify) and a website's (Youtube) availability depends on my audio settings. I also notice this problem when I don't play audio for a while. If I want to play Spotify or watch a video, I need to repeat the process of unplugging/plugging the headphones back in to "reset" Windows' sound settings.

Comment: When Windows changes default playback or recording endpoint, it reorders MME/WinMM endpoint numbers, making new default endpoint to be first and have number 0. If the application uses WASAPI or other modern audio interfaces, or uses MME/WinMM and refers a default endpoint, it is not affected. But if the application uses MME/WinMM and refers the endpoint by its number, determining this number only on startup, reordering may cause this number to become invalid, or to be associated with another endpoint.

Try to restart audio applications that stop producing sounds after the sleep.

Comment: @EugeneMuzychenko - Is that the only remedy? That's what I'm currently doing, but not sure if there's a less clunky way around it.

Comment: If one or more audio applications involved into your setup use MME/WinMM and access particular endpoints by their numbers, this is the only remedy. But in your case, there may be some other peculiarities, so it is better to make some tests.

The problem is that Windows default audio endpoint policy is focused on a typical user who connects or disconnects audio devices very rarely, and prefers all sounds to go to/from the same direction. MS guys consider that any user should be satisfied by this policy, and don't offer an opportunity to tune it.